# Downloading File from Internet and Saving it in Android Internal Storage

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-internal-storage

How can i download file from server and save it in android internal storage?

Till now i was using DownloadManager Class but DownloadManager allows file to save in external storage only.

What other way can be implemented?

Comment: "Till now i was using DownloadManager Class but DownloadManager allows file to save in external storage only" -- with a `FileProvider`, you might be able to get `DownloadManager` to download to your internal storage. I have not tried that, though. "What other way can be implemented?" -- use `HttpURLConnection`. Or, use OkHttp3.